# What may cause a thread id to be -1?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex, stdthread

I've currently been playing around with concurrent objects, based on [Herb Sutter's presentation](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-Concurrency-and-Parallelism). I'm currently using Visual Studio 2012 with November CTP (could not check the stuff below in another way, Clang doesn't like class members in decltypes, g++ did not like anything on Windows).

Doing so, I've faced a curious bug with a thread-id being -1.
Consider the following code:

```
__workerThread([=]() -> void {    
    std::cerr << std::endl; 
    while (!__done) 
    { 
        this->__innerqueue.pop()(); 
    }    
})
```

It's just the initialization of a `std::thread` with a lambda function - nothing spectacular, I thought.
But without the first line that forces a call to std::cerr (no optimization), this thread's id appears to be -1 (due to the debugger), while otherwise, it's like it should be.

The problem with this thread ID occurs when executing

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(this->__accessMutex);
```

inside the [message-queue](https://github.com/DorianGrey/Concurrent/blob/master/concurrent/queue.hpp), since it crashes somewhere in the lower APIs (mutex.c).

Has anyone got an idea what may cause this curious behavior ? Adding the call to `std::cerr` is just a nasty workaround for the moment, and I'd like to get rid of it ...

You can find the full source at [Github](https://github.com/DorianGrey/Concurrent) if you want to play around with it.

Comment: FYI, identifiers containing adjacent underscores are reserved by the implementation.

Comment: Have you tried to call `get_id()`? The `id` of an `std::thread` may even be generated on-demand AFAIK.

Comment: I don't think many people will want to go to Github to look at code. Can you minimize the code and post it here?

Comment: The fact that `__done` is not atomic nor protected by a memory barrier is definitely a problem, but I don't know that it's the particular problem that you see manifesting...

Comment: @Praetorian I know that, but at the moment, there is no relevant conflict. Suppose I've been working with python too much...
@AndyProwl I did that before, yes. Only calling it does not prevent the error, but using it with `std::cout` or `std::cerr` does. Optimization stuff, I suppose.

Comment: @GManNickG The code snippets I've mentioned are as small as possible. I cannot cut down the full source to post something compilable without changing the intentions, which may cause misleading distractions during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like an initializer problem. The thread runs before the concurrent queue is fully created (a race). The `std::cerr` probably delays the thread just long enough to make it work.

try swapping the two lines:

```
std::thread __workerThread;
mutable concurrent::queue<std::function<void()>, std::queue> __innerqueue;
```

Swapping should create the `__innerqueue` before the thread and it should work as advertised.

Comment: I was wondering if that may work... and yes, it does, thank you.